# Dynamic way to collapse multiple rows of distinct data into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data base that records the attributes of users at certain periods of time. A simplified example:

```
UserID  Year Measure1 Measures2
---------------------------------
1,       2000,     3,     4
1,       2001,     5,     6
```

What I need to do is collapse multiple rows of data into columns

```
UserID Measure1_2000  Measure1_2001
-----------------------------------
1,      3,               5
```

Where the end result is that each row tracks users attributes across time. I would prefer to write this as a function or stored procedure, where the number of years that are collapsed into columns is supplied as an argument, so the table structure has to be generated dynamically.

I could use a big table pivot statement, but then the number of columns would be static, and the code would be messy, because I have to collapse multiple types of data into columns.

I tried using some dynamic sql that would iterate through a while loop, joining a list of user ids against the master table, but it is way, way too slow. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times around here. Search for dynamic pivot. You won't be able to do this in a function because it will require dynamic sql. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]dynamic+pivot

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you. I googled and searched quite a bit. I haven't been able to find what I need yet, or I don't understand what I am looking at :). Would you be able to point me to a specific example? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. Click the link I posted and view the very first one on the list.

Comment: Definitely didn't understand what I was looking at! I think I am piecing it together. That is enough to get me started, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @user3538411 I found this example that looks very similar to what you're trying to do.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b473b/1   good luck :)